# Django Error when creating model entries with Django shell

Tags: django, django-models, valueerror

My model looks like this.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    eval_id = models.ForeignKey(Evaluation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher_id = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score1 = models.IntegerField()
    score2 = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('eval_id','teacher_id','class_id')
```

Here eval_id,teacher_id and class_id are defined accordingly in their respective models

```
eval_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
teacher_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
co_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length=5)
```

Model class for Teacher:

```
 class Teacher(models.Model):
        teacher_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
        teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        teacher_age = models.IntegerField()
        teacher_doj = models.DateField()
        subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.teacher_name
```

I get the below error when I try to create an entry for the model via the shell

```
from trial.models import Test
>>> t1 = Test('1','AC23002','C001','48','50')
```

I get the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 807, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 837, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 904, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 954, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 664, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1199, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 871, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1165, in as_sql
    val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 963, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 770, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 762, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1853, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AC23003'
```

Can someone please help me identify the error in object creation.

The Teacher table is as below:

```
mysql> select * from trial_teacher;
+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| teacher_id | teacher_name | teacher_age | teacher_doj |
+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| AC23001    | Tina         |          32 | 2017-04-10  |
| AC23002    | Rina         |          31 | 2009-04-10  |
| AC23003    | Tom          |          35 | 2009-04-10  |
| AC23004    | Henry        |          56 | 2009-04-10  |
| AC23005    | Simon        |          32 | 2009-05-10  |
+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe trial_teacher;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| teacher_id   | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| teacher_name | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| teacher_age  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| teacher_doj  | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Evaluation table:

```
mysql> mysql> select * from trial_evaluation;
+---------+------------+----------------------------+
| eval_id | eval_name  | date                       |
+---------+------------+----------------------------+
|       1 | 2014_Term1 | 2017-01-01 10:30:00.000000 |
|       2 | 2014_Term2 | 2014-04-01 10:30:00.000000 |
|       3 | 2014_Term3 | 2014-11-01 08:30:00.000000 |
+---------+------------+----------------------------+
```

Similarly 'C001' exists in the class Table

Comment: teacher_id is supposed to receive the primary key of the model Teacher, but you are giving a string 'AC23003'.

Comment: But I have defined `teacher_id` as the primary key in my Teacher table. So how do i correct it?

Comment: nothing to correct. just pass primary key of one of the record in Teacher table when you create the object using shell.

Comment: 'AC23003' itself is the primary key in the teacher table. I have updated my question to include teacher table details.

Comment: Oh okay. Can you update question with the Teacher model as well ?

Comment: I have updated my question with the tables and the models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
Test(eval_id_id='1',teacher_id_id='AC23002',class_id_id='C001',score1='48',score2='50')
```

Django appends '_id' for all names related to keys. So if you are using the key value directly, use '_id'.

OR,

When using field name described in model.

```
Test(eval_id = Evaluation.objects.get(eval_id=xxx),...)
```

First method is efficient.

Comment: Thanks. When I pass the values with the arguments like you suggested it works fine!